# it doesn't show an alert if one textarea is empty or less than 5 characters

Tags: jquery

Below is my coding which is suppose to validate textareas which are empty or contains 5 characters or less.

```
function validation() {

                var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
    var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;    

    alertValidation= "";
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...

    var textAreaO = $(".textAreaQuestion");

    if (textAreaO.val() == ""){
        alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
    } else if (textAreaO.val().length < 5){
        alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
    }


    if(alertValidation != "")
    {
        alert(alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

     return true;
}
```

The problem is that lets say I have 2 textareas with the same class (.textAreaQuestion), then if one one of the two textareas is empty or less than 5 characters, then there is no validation (no alert appears) which is incorrect as it should appear. It only appears if both textareas are empty or less than 5 characters. So how can this code be manipulated so that if there is a textarea out of many textareas which is empty or less than 5 characters, then show the alert?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers everybody, when I reach reputation of 15 I will upvote all answers as all answers look correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returns the value of the first matched element:

> Description: Get the current value of **the first element in the set of matched elements**.

You should iterate through the matched elements to treat them separately. Something like this:

```
$(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {
    if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
        alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xYcdp/)**

Answer (score 0):

If your selector matches more than one element calling `.val()` will return only the value for the **first** element matched. If you want to validate all of them, you'll need to iterate over all of the elements using the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

Comment: so I just add `$(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {` above the if statement?

Comment: Essentially, yes - though you can do `textAreaO.each(...)` since you've already saved the result of the selector into that variable. A few other points on the rest of the code: You don't have the `var` keyword on your initial declaration for `alertValidation`, but I don't think it's intended to be global. Your `if/else if` statement could be condensed into one `if` statement with an OR condition, since the code being executed in both cases is identical.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your  `.textAreaQuestion` using [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var textAreaO = $(".textAreaQuestion");

textAreaO.each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == ""){
    alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
  } else if ($(this).val().length < 5){
    alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
  }
});
//...
```